# Android - How do I know its the closed testing app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I tell the phone has automatically updated the downloadable app to the closed alpha / beta testing version? Sorry, I just found this functionality and am amazed by the approach as it does not make much sense to me.